# Problema na data: 1919/1010/2018181818 03:15:16 PM

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Está tudo certo mas na hora de exibir ou salvar no banco a data, está ficando assim 1919/1010/2018181818 03:15:16 PM... não sei qual problema, ou se errei em algum lugar. Alguém sabe o porque disso?? pode ver que a hora está certa mas só acontece isso na data.

---

Página settings(php):

(index)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dateformat', lang('date_format'), 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('timeformat', lang('time_format'), 'required');
```

($data)

```
'dateformat' => DEMO ? 'jS F Y' : $this->input->post('dateformat'),
                'timeformat' => DEMO ? 'h:i A' : $this->input->post('timeformat'),
```

página footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var base_url = '<?=base_url();?>';

    var dateformat = '<?=$Settings->dateformat;?>', timeformat = '<?= $Settings->timeformat ?>';

    <?php unset($Settings->protocol, $Settings->smtp_host, $Settings->smtp_user, $Settings->smtp_pass, $Settings->smtp_port, $Settings->smtp_crypto, $Settings->mailpath, $Settings->timezone, $Settings->setting_id, $Settings->default_email, $Settings->version, $Settings->stripe, $Settings->stripe_secret_key, $Settings->stripe_publishable_key); ?>

    var Settings = <?= json_encode($Settings); ?>;
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.mm_<?=$m?>').addClass('active');
        $('#<?=$m?>_<?=$v?>').addClass('active');
    });

</script>
```

---

Página all.js:

```
 $('.clock').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    function Now() { return new Date().getTime(); }
    var stamp = Math.floor(Now() / 1000);
    var time = date(dateformat+' '+timeformat, stamp);
    $('.clock').text(time);

    window.setInterval(function(){
        var stamp = Math.floor(Now() / 1000);
        var time = date(dateformat+' '+timeformat, stamp);
        $('.clock').text(time);
    }, 10000);
```

---

Página header:

```
<li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#" class="clock"></a></li>
```

Comment: Amigo, seja bem vindo ao forum do stack overflow.

Coloque seu código, mas diria que tem algo repetido.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Realmente. O problema erra que o parâmetro estava sendo passa pelo banco, dd/mm/Yyyy. alterei para d/m/Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, creio que na hora de exibir você deve está usando algo como `dd/mm/Yyyy H:i:s` porém no php a formatação da data não exige mais de uma letra para identificar qual parte da data será impressa, tente algo como `d/m/Y H:i:s` para formata-la

Comment: O problema erra que o parâmetro estava sendo passa pelo banco, dd/mm/Yyyy. alterei para d/m/Y.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo parecido com este exemplo para trabalhar com datas.

```
// Definindo dados de teste aqui ou mandado via formulário.
$_POST["Data"] = "19/10/2018 16:30";
// Define a sua zona geografica.
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
// Gerar objeto DateTime.
$oData = new DateTime();
// Define a data para o objeto DateTime.
$_POST["Data"] = str_replace("/", "-", $_POST["Data"]);
$oData->setTimestamp(strtotime($_POST["Data"]));
// Mostra os dados
print($oData->format("d/m/Y H:i:s"));
```